# Material design on tablets Pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, android-studio, tablet, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm actually on Android Studio 1.0.2.
I'm trying implement Material design on tablets with 4.1.2 Android version

I want do that:
[image: tabletsToolbar]

okay, I'm reading the nexts blogs:

- http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html
- https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

**Problems:**

I have on *values/themes.xml* the next code:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Here we setting appcompat’s actionBarStyle -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>

    <!-- ...and here we setting appcompat’s color theming attrs -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_red</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_awesome_darker_red</item>

    <!-- The rest of your attributes -->
</style>
```

It report an error like that:

[image: error on android]

**(first problem)** What is the problem?

**(Second problem)** How can implement Material design on pre-lollipop tablets? How can I do a similar design? (First blue toolbar and inside content with another toolbar)

Really, I've tried before asking...

Thanks

Comment: I think by "Android 5.0" you mean "Material Design". Android 5.0 *is* Lollipop, so talking about implementing Android 5.0 without Lollipop is a non-sequitur.

Comment: you're right, edited

Comment: There's no need for "(Android 5.0)" everywhere. You're just trying to implement the Material Design look and feel, right? If so, that's all you need to say.

Comment: Right, It is the first contact I have with the material design...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Problem:** It looks like your `themes.xml` file isn't properly written. Your top level element should be `<resources>`. Try instead...

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Here we setting appcompat’s actionBarStyle -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>

        <!-- ...and here we setting appcompat’s color theming attrs -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_red</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_awesome_darker_red</item>

        <!-- The rest of your attributes -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Second Problem:** You may need to provide some code showing what you've done to this point so it's not a matter of someone writing the entire thing for you.

Comment: Thanks, it works good. Okay, I will, add the code for my layout and my class